# aws_launch_template makes batch job in runnable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-batch, launch-template

I added a launch template to IaC and and when I run the batch job it stuck in runnable state

this my launch template code :

```
 resource "aws_launch_template" "conversion_launch_template" {
      name = "conversion-launch-template"
    
  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 80
    }
  }

  iam_instance_profile {
    name = "conversion-pipeline-batch-iam-instance-profile"
  }
}
```

and in "aws_batch_compute_environment" resource I reference the launch template inside the compute ressource block :

```
resource "aws_batch_compute_environment" "conversion_pipeline" {
  compute_environment_name = "conversion-pipeline-batch-compute-environment"



  compute_resources {
    instance_role = aws_iam_instance_profile.conversion_pipeline_batch.arn

    instance_type = var.conversion_pipeline_instance_type
    max_vcpus     = var.conversion_pipeline_max_vcpus
    min_vcpus     = 0

    

    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.conversion_pipeline_batch.id
    ]
    subnets = var.subnets

    type = "EC2"
    
    launch_template {
      launch_template_id = aws_launch_template.conversion_launch_template.id
    }

  }

  service_role = aws_iam_role.conversion_pipeline_batch_service_role.arn
  type         = "MANAGED"

  tags = {
    environment = var.env
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code blocks to the question.

Comment: Take a look here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/batch-job-stuck-runnable-status/.